# Angular: reset filters

Tags: angular, filter

I have a search filter by id on a table. The filter does the search correctly, but I would like the Reset button (Clear) to reset it for me and leave the table with all the ids again, but I don't know how to do this very well. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="gFilter()" method="post">

 <div>
         <label for="id">Ids: </label>
        <input name="idP" id="idP" class="f-control" placeholder="Id" (keyup)="Key($event)">
         </div>

<input type="submit" value="Clear" id="submit_button" (click)="reset()">          
                

     </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
valueId:any;

Key(event)
  {
     this.valueId=event.target.value;
  }

 gFilter(){
 
    if (this.valueId!=null)
      {
        if(this.pFiltros==null)
        {
        this.pFiltros=this.ids.filter(x=>x.idP.toString()!=null && x.idP.toString().includes(this.valueId));
        
        }
        else{
          this.pFiltros=this.pFiltros.filter(x=>x.idP.toString()!=null && x.idP.toString().includes(this.valueId));
        
        }
        
      }
  }


 reset(){
  
   ¿?
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep two copies of the array, the original one and the filtered one. You bind the fitlered array to the html, and when the user filters you manipulate the filtered array to show the results to the template.

When the user resets you set the filtered array to the original.

Example:

```
originalArray: any[] = [];
filteredArray: any[] = [];

loadArrayData() {
  //.. fetch the data
  this.originalArray = data;
  this.filteredArray = data;
}

// this is triggered on filter
filterData(condition: any) {
  this.filteredArray.filter(item => 
    //.. filter the array by id, or however you want
  })
}

resetFilter() {
  this.filteredArray = this.originalArray;
}
```

*PS: sorry i didn't use your code, i couldn't understand much, hope this answer helps you*